# Как сделать опции allSelected если выбрана другая опция?

Tags: typescript, angular

Подскажите что не так делаю, сейчас у меня если выбрана опция в селекте allSelected и я выбираю любую из списка то allSelected пропадает заменяясь на новую опцию, а как теперь сделать наоборот что б если у меня выбрана любая опция кроме allSelected, и я б выбирал allSelected то все опции б исчезали кроме allSelected, что не так ?

```
this.form.get('selectedOptions').valueChanges.subscribe((options: string[]) => {
  if (options.length > 1 && options.includes('allSelected')) {
    const withoutAllSelected = options.filter(option => option !== 'allSelected');
    this.form.get('selectedOptions').patchValue(withoutAllSelected, { emitEvent: false });
  } else if (options.length > 1 && !options.includes('allSelected')) {
    const withoutAllOptionsSelected = options.filter(option => option !== 'allSelected');
    this.form.get('selectedOptions').patchValue(withoutAllOptionsSelected, { emitEvent: false });
  }
});
```

Comment: что приходит в options? Как ты определяешь какую галку нажал?

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью функции [`pairwise()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pairwise) из библиотеки [*RxJs*](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library):

```
this.form.get('selectedOptions').valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(this.form.get('selectedOptions').value),
    pairwise())
  .subscribe(([previousOptions, currentOptions]: [string[], string[]]) => {
    const allSelectedIndex = currentOptions.indexOf('allSelected');
    if (allSelectedIndex !== -1 && previousOptions.length > 1 && !previousOptions.includes('allSelected')) {
      this.form.get('selectedOptions').setValue(['allSelected'], { emitEvent: false });
    } else if (currentOptions.length > 1 && currentOptions.includes('allSelected')) {
      const withoutAllSelected = currentOptions.filter(option => option !== 'allSelected');
      this.form.get('selectedOptions').patchValue(withoutAllSelected, { emitEvent: false });
    }
  });
```